Prove that $a_n$ is both upper and lower bounded

Suppose $$f(x)=\ln(1+x)$$
and
$$
  a_n = \overbrace{
    f\cdots f}^\text{n}(n)
 $$
Prove that for any $n>1$, $$\frac{2n}{n^2+2}<a_n<n^{(2^{-n})}$$

I'm not able to figure out an inequality that combines both logarithmic and polynomial functions. All I could do was induction, but at the last step I got blanked.
How to proceed? Any help is greatly appreciated.
EDIT
For the base case $n=2$, we have $\frac{2×2}{2^2+2^2}=0.5<\ln(1+\ln(1+2))\approx 0.74$
Let's assume that the inequality is true for any $n=m$ 
$\implies \frac{2m}{m^2+2}<a_m$
Now we have to prove that,
$\frac{2(m+1)}{(m+1)^2+2}<a_{m+1}$
I'm stuck here, how to proceed?

If you show the work you've done to this point, others might be able to help you finish the argument. You might be really close and just missing a simple fact or two.

Since $n^{2^{-n}}> 1$, showing that $a_n \leq 1$ does the trick for the upper bound.

Can you express $a_n$ in terms of $a_{n-1}$ or other prior terms?

The same question was posted yesterday. Is this from an exam?

Here's the duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5012452

@Karl that question is deleted and I don't have the perk to view the deleted questions...and idk if it came in an exam, I saw this question being posted by someone on this site but due to the poor standard of the post, it was deleted....I took an ss of the question in time so that I can try it later

Starting by computing fist few term we get $a_1\approx 0.69, a_2\approx 0.74, a_3\approx 0.626, a_4\approx 0.514$. We can see that form second therm this sequence is decreasing and it can be showed easily. For $n\geq 2$ holds inequality $n>\ln(n+2)$ and starting from this point we get
$$ n+1>1+\ln(n+1+1) $$
$$ \ln(n+1)>\ln(1+\ln((n+1)+1)) $$
$$ \ldots $$
$$ a_n=\ln(1+\ln(1+\ldots \ln(n+1))) > \ln(1+\ln(1+\ldots \ln((n+1)+1)))=a_{n+1} $$
where on right sides we always have one more logarithm and the inner argument is $(n+1)+1$ so after $n$ repeating of alternately adding one and taking natural log we get this inequality. That means $(a_n)$ is decreasing from second therm and because $a_2<1$ we get upper bound because $n^{2^{-n}}>1$.
Bounding from below we can easily check for $n=1, 2, 3$ and it indeed holds. For $n\geq 4$ we will prove something stronger: $\frac 2 n <a_n$. Of course if $\frac 2 n <a_n$ then $\frac{2n}{n^2+2}<a_n$ because $\frac{2n}{n^2+2}<\frac{2n}{n^2}=\frac 2 n$. Because $a_4\approx 0.514$ then for $n=4$ holds $\frac 2 4 < a_4$. Now let's use induction. Assume this inequality holds for some $n$. For $n+1$ we have
$$ a_{n+1}=\ln(1+\ldots \ln(n+2))>\ln(1+\ldots \ln(n+1))=\ln(1+a_n)>\ln(1+\frac 2 n)> $$
$$ > \frac 2 n - \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac{4}{n^2}+\frac 1 3 \cdot \frac{8}{n^3}-\frac 1 4 \cdot \frac{16}{n^4}\geq \frac{2}{n+1} $$
where the last inequality holds because $\frac 2 n -\frac 2 {n^2}+\frac{8}{3n^3}-\frac{4}{n^4}>\frac{2}{n+1}$ is equivalent to $\frac{2n^2}{3}-\frac{4n}{3}\geq 0$ which is true because $n\geq 4$ and the previous inequality comes from Taylor series expansion of $\ln(1+x).$ That finishes induction step and also finishes the proof

The upper bound can be replaced by $1$ and for each natural $n$, $a_n$ lies between the required bounds. Indeed, we can check this directly for $n\le 9$:
$$\begin{matrix}
n & a_n & \frac{2n}{n^2+2}\\
1 & 0.6931\dots & 0.6666\dots\\
2 & 0.7412\dots & 0.6666\dots\\
3 & 0.6258\dots & 0.5454\dots\\
4 & 0.5143\dots & 0.4444\dots\\
5 & 0.4281\dots & 0.3703\dots\\
6 & 0.3632\dots & 0.3157\dots\\
7 & 0.3138\dots & 0.2745\dots\\
8 & 0.2753\dots & 0.2424\dots\\
9 & 0.2448\dots & 0.2168\dots
\end{matrix}$$
Now we can apply induction. It is justified by the inequality $\ln(1+x)<x-1$ for each $x\ge 3$ for the lower bound and by the inequality $g(x)>0$ for each $x\ge 9$ for the upper bound.
Here
$$g(x)=\ln\left(1+\frac{2x}{x^2+2}\right)-\frac{2(x+1)}{(x+1)^2+2}.$$
Then $g(9)>0$ and
$$g'(x)=-2\cdot \frac{x^4-6x^3-19x^2-28x-14}{(x^2+2x+3)^2(x^2+2x+2)(x^2+2)}<0.$$
Since $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)=0$, we have $g(x)>0$ for each $x\ge 9$.
PS. The computer calculations suggest that $$a_n=\frac 2{n}+O\left(\frac{\ln n}{n^2}\right).$$
